# Manually installing Sun Java and Debian/Ubuntu virtual java packages

Tags: ubuntu, java, sun

I've installed Sun Java 6 manually since Canonical has removed it from its package repo (I use Ubuntu 12.04). Now I have the following problem: when I want to install a package which depends on Java via a virtual Java packages (java2-runtime or default-jre) the package manager complains that Java is not installed and tries to install the default JRE (OpenJDK on my system). Is there a way to manually mark the virtual package (e.g. java6-runtime) to be installed? This must be a common problem - how is it best addressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the [equivs](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=equivs) package to create a dummy package which provides the missing java6-runtime dependency, which will make dpkg/apt think that this dependency is satisfied.  Here are some basic instructions [on the debian wiki](http://wiki.debian.org/Packaging/HackingDependencies?highlight=%28equivs%29).

Also note that [openjdk-6-jre](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=openjdk-6-jre) is the free version of java, which is still available from ubuntu, and generally just works, and might be a much more simple alternative.